Is the inconsistency between conversions allowed by std::not_fn and std::function constructor intended?
If you have something like this,
struct Foo {
};

constexpr auto pred = [](){
    return Foo{};
};

calling std::not_fn(pred) will fail to compile, expectedly.
However, adding an explicit conversion operator from Foo to bool,
struct Foo {
    explicit operator bool() {
        return true;
    }
};

is enough to make std::not_fn(pred) compile.
This at first seemed reasonable to me. But then I realiazed that:
    std::function<bool(int)> f{std::not_fn(pred)}; // compiles
    std::function<bool(int)> g{pred};              // fails to compile

I do see some reason for the permissiveness of std::not_fn: based on its name, it is supposed to negate a predicate, so fair enough if it tries to convert the return type of the given function to bool.
But why shouldn't std::function adopt a similar policy? After all, given a function of type ConvertibleToFoo(Bar), what would be wrong in constructing a std::function<Foo(ConvertibleToBar)>?
Or, if std::function doesn't allow that, why does std::not_fn allow it?
Indeed, it seems to me that the fact that std::not_fn is able to act on functions that return a non-bool-but-explicitly-convertible-to-bool type is a happy (or not happy) side effect of the fact that it uses !, in its implementation, in front of the return type of the provided function.

Interesting blog post from Arthur O’Dwyer regarding covariance and contravariance.

I believe the ! operator is the reason, as it should explicitly convert the type to bool first (if it's not overloaded).

Are you asking why implicit conversion is not done with explicit operator bool()? Remove explicit and everything works: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Yn7bK6hr4

@LHLaurini, yes, std::not_fn's usage of ! is what allows the first line of the last snippet to work.

@Enlico -- naturally, logical operators are excluded from explicit bool rule

@Gene, yes, so the fact that std::not_fn accepts functions that don't return bool but something with explicit conversion operator to bool seems more like a coincidence than by design.

@Enlico -- it an asymmetry in the language, logical operators are not defined for function objects, instead it's a library facility (not_fn), which has to obey different rules.

!thing will use an explicit operator bool conversion if available, because that is an explicit bool situation.  Just as if (thing) will use an explicit operator bool conversion if available.

Enlico, I hope I didn't destroy your question, but I think the lawyering tag is the one that makes it even better.

I'm not sure a lawyer tag fits. The question seems to be more asking a rationale which won't be found usually, esp. for older things like not_fn and function. And I don't think there's much more to say except: not_fn is the function-object form of "!" and it should act like "!", which means allowing contextual bool conversions. function acts as if you assign the return value to something... so it allows implicit conversions. [C++ has a lot of different contexts where different conversions are allowed.]

std::not_fn models return !std::invoke(/*...*/); and std::function models return std::invoke(/*...*/);. I think that is all.

In particular not_fn doesn't depend in any form specifically on bool, as long as the ! operator works it is fine, regardless of any return type. std::function on the other hand needs to have a fixed type to coerce to because it abstracts over multiple callables, not just a single one.
